# How to convert String excel string into JSON for large data file

Tags: javascript, python, json, pandas

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CBsN.png)

I've data like this how I can convert String to JSON

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are getting that, but you can create a vba macro that iterates (with  do while) over each cell and build a json string in the format "property": cellValue(i). Then get the full string as json formatted: { yourFullString }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a key/value format, so I'm assuming you want your value to be what's in the image, but what about your key?

For Python, take a look at [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Here's an example of how you might loop through all of those rows:

```
import json
import openpyxl

xl_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('myxl-file.xlsx)
xl_doc = xl_wb.active

first_row = 1
last_row = 10
values = {}

for i in range(first_row, last_row):
   cell = xl_doc.cell(row=i, column=1)
   values[i] = cell.value

json_from_xl = json.dumps(values)
```

Comment: I don't have any Keys,I can mask key

Comment: @SaifulAlam in the post I posted I made the key simply the row number. You can make it whatever you'd like

Answer (score 0):

In python,

`df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')`

and then `df.to_json(orient="values")`

options for orient

```
‘split’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], ‘data’ -> [values]}

‘records’ : list like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]

‘index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}

‘columns’ : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}

‘values’ : just the values array

‘table’ : dict like {‘schema’: {schema}, ‘data’: {data}}
```